# How to change image on hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I hover on the first image it changes and the second div image is also changed and this process in reverse when I hover the first div image is changed and change itself using jQuery?

CLICK ON THIS LINK 
https://www.studioairport.nl/ AND GO TO THE **Meet our team** CONTENT

```css
.our-team{
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.our-team img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.our-team .team-content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 45px 18px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: all 0.20s ease 0s;
}
/*.our-team:hover .team-content{
    transform: translateX(0);
}*/
.our-team .team-content .post-title{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.our-team .team-content .post{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #cb95e1;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.our-team .description{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.our-team .team_social{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
}
.our-team .team_social li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.our-team .team_social li a{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: border 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.our-team .team_social li a:hover{
    border-color: transparent;
}
.our-team .team-prof{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 20px 16px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: all 0.20s ease 0s;
}
/*.our-team:hover .team-prof{
    transform: translateX(100%);
}*/
.our-team .team-prof .post-title{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.our-team .team-prof .post{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #cb95e1;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    .our-team{ margin-bottom: 20px; }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="our-team">
                <img class="xyz"  src="http://jqueryrain.com/tutorial/our-team/demo30/images/img-2.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="team-content">
                    <h3 class="post-title">Williamson</h3>
                    <span class="post">Web Desginer</span>
                    <p class="description">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio exercitationem facilis laborum perferendis quasi, ratione.
                    </p>
                    <ul class="team_social">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="team-prof">
                    <h3 class="post-title">Williamson</h3>
                    <span class="post">Web Desginer</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="our-team">
                <img src="http://jqueryrain.com/tutorial/our-team/demo30/images/img-1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="team-content">
                    <h3 class="post-title">Williamson</h3>
                    <span class="post">Web Desginer</span>
                    <p class="description">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio exercitationem facilis laborum perferendis quasi, ratione.
                    </p>
                    <ul class="team_social">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="team-prof">
                    <h3 class="post-title">Williamson</h3>
                    <span class="post">Web Desginer</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="our-team">
                <img src="http://jqueryrain.com/tutorial/our-team/demo30/images/img-1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="team-content">
                    <h3 class="post-title">Williamson</h3>
                    <span class="post ">Web Desginer</span>
                    <p class="description">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio exercitationem facilis laborum perferendis quasi, ratione.
                    </p>
                    <ul class="team_social">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="team-prof">
                    <h3 class="post-title">Williamson</h3>
                    <span class="post">Web Desginer</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="our-team">
                <img src="http://jqueryrain.com/tutorial/our-team/demo30/images/img-1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="team-content">
                    <h3 class="post-title">Williamson</h3>
                    <span class="post">Web Desginer</span>
                    <p class="description">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio exercitationem facilis laborum perferendis quasi, ratione.
                    </p>
                    <ul class="team_social">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="team-prof">
                    <h3 class="post-title">Williamson</h3>
                    <span class="post">Web Desginer</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please could you rephrase your explanation, it is very difficult to follow.

Comment: I cant see any image change on hover, am i missing something?

Comment: @pratik  your question is not making any sense

Comment: You are spelling "designer" wrong btw.

Answer (score 4):

you can use it with simple inline javascript

```
<img src="http://jqueryrain.com/tutorial/our-team/demo30/images/img-1.jpg" alt="" onmouseover="this.src='http://jqueryrain.com/tutorial/our-team/demo30/images/img-2.jpg'"  onmouseout="this.src='http://jqueryrain.com/tutorial/our-team/demo30/images/img-1.jpg'">
```

or using jquery

```
<img src="http://jqueryrain.com/tutorial/our-team/demo30/images/img-1.jpg" alt="" data-hover-src="this.src='http://jqueryrain.com/tutorial/our-team/demo30/images/img-2.jpg'"  data-normal-src="this.src='http://jqueryrain.com/tutorial/our-team/demo30/images/img-1.jpg'">

$("img")
  .on( "mouseenter", function() {
     $(this).attr("src", $(this).data('hover-src'));
 })
 .on( "mouseleave", function() {
     $(this).attr("src", $(this).data('normal-src'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an attribute in each of your `<img />` tags, something like `data-replacement`:

```
<img class="xyz" data-replacement="/image/my_replacement_image.jpg" src="..." alt="" />
```

Then you can use jQuery [`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method:

```
$(".our-team img").hover(function() {
    var img = $(this);
    // store current src in image data
    img.data('src', img.attr("src"));
    // replace
    img.attr("src", img.data('replacement'));
},
function(){
    // restore src
    $(this).attr('src', img.data('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**set background image using css instead of html**
*Try This*

HTML :

```
<div class="our-team">
   <div class="img-block"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-block{ 
 background: url("img-1.jpg") no repeat;
 background-position:2px 2px;
 }
```

**Change image on hover:**

```
.img-block:hover{ 
      background:url("img-2.jpg") no repeat;
 }
```

You can set background position and required image path acoording to your need

Answer (score 0):

**Try this also**

Take an id in img tag

```
#idname:hover{ background:url("img2.png"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using img tag, If you use those image in background. It is easy to handle it in css itself.

This is an HTML mockup:

```
<div style="background-image: url(image-1.jpg)"></div>
```

Here is CSS:

```
div:hover {
background-image: url(image-2.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint to 'JavaScript/jQuery Less' Solution. Recommend you not to use jQuery/Javascript for this simple task.

```html
    <div class='image-container'>
    <img class="xyz" src="http://pnge.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/images.jpg" alt="" height='100' width='200' />
    <img class="xyz-replacement" src="http://chainimage.com/images/3d-wallpapers-amazing-wallpapers-tigers-wallpapers-white-tiger.jpg" alt="" height='100' width='200' />
    </div>

<style>
      .image-container{
     position: relative;
    }
    .image-container:hover .xyz-replacement {
     display: block;
    }
    .xyz-replacement{
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
     z-index: 9;
    }
  
  </style>
```